# How do I read from a dictionary, and whatever the input from the dictionary is put in it gets multipled by a variable called total?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

It's my first day of python, I've been hitched on this for a while.

I have a dictionary which contains three values, "Luxury" "Standard" and "Economy". These have a key of a price per square meters, and I was wondering how I can make it so that when the user picks one of the selected values, it will then multiply the the total (gathered from other code) with that key. I need to keep the .capitalize part for user validation.

Thanks guys!

I'm half way there, somebody suggested me some code to try and add but I wasn't entirely sure how to implement it.

```
paints = {
"Luxury" : 1.75,
"Standard": 1.00,
"Economy": 0.80,
}
while True:
    paintType = input("What type of paint would you like to  use? \n Luxury \n Standard \n Economy" "\n ")
    paintType.capitalize()
    if user_input.capitalize() in paints
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is what we call is an immutable object, which in simpler terms mean that it cannot be modified in-place, and it gives you a new string whenever you perform an operation of it like `capitalize`, so we will assign the value of `paintType.capitalize()` to a new variable.

Then we can use this variable in the `if` condition to check if the input is present in the keys of dictionary `paints`, which is what we do in the if condition `if paintType.capitalize() in paints` for example, and then you can perform the multiplication

```
paints = {
"Luxury" : 1.75,
"Standard": 1.00,
"Economy": 0.80,
}
while True:
    paintType = input("What type of paint would you like to  use? \n Luxury \n Standard \n Economy" "\n ")

    #Assign return value of capitalize to user_input variable
    user_input = paintType.capitalize()

    #Check for input being in the keys and if present multiply with total
    if user_input in paints:
        result = paints[user_input] * total
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a dictionary value using:

```
price = paints[user_input]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to check if user's input matches one of your dictionary keys. If so, you can store the corresponding value for  later user

```
if paintType.capitalize() in paints.keys()
        value = paints[paintType.capitalize()]
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
paint_types = {
"Luxury" : 1.75,
"Standard": 1.00,
"Economy": 0.80,
}

while True:
    user_input = input("What type of paint would you like to  use? \n Luxury \n Standard \n Economy" "\n ")
    user_input = user_input.capitalize()

    if user_input in paint_types:
        total = total * paint_types[user_input]
        break
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying that total isn't defined?

Comment: Please refactor it based on your other part of code